# Jodd jDateTime TimeZone: How to change timezone?

Tags: jodd

http://jodd.org/doc/jdatetime.html#timezones-and-dst

The following example shows the current time in Japan:

```
JDateTime jdt = new JDateTime();
jdt.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Japan"));
System.out.println(jdt);
```

I've tried the above example, setting the timezone to different values as well, but it always returns exactly the same thing: local time.

Maybe I am doing something wrong, or maybe it's a bug.  Has anyone else seen this?

Comment: did my answer helped?

Answer (score 0):

Just keep reading:

> Furthermore, it is possible just to set the timezone, without changing the time.  And something useful - to change timezone, using method `changeTimeZone()`.

Yeah, documentation is misleading :) So let me explain:

- `setTimeZone` simply set the timezone information, *without* changing time.
- `changeTimeZone` actually does the change, using passed timezone and current one :)

We will update docs!